# How to minimize diffusion in undirected weighted graph

Tags: weighted-graphs, social-networks

I've got a work that has to do with networks, where each edge has a weight ($w\in(0,1)$) and some random set of nodes are 'infected'. I don't know which nodes are (or how many). The diffusion spread is according to linear threshold model (with some random threshold $\theta\in(0.3,0.5)$. I'm allowed to delete only $10\%$ of edges from the original graph, before the parameters are set (I don't know the initial infected nodes, nor the threshold a-priori).

I've tried multiple methods like:

1. **removing highest weighted edges first** - that results good performance when only small amount of initial infected nodes is given.
2. **removing local-bridges** - I've sorted the edges by neighbourhood overlap, and then removed by weight. - This works good for low thresholds.
3. **Multiple variations of vertex cover, edge cover, centrality, betweenness etc** - all underperformed the "naive" remove by weight approach (presented in (1)).
4. *Clustering heuristics* - tried to construct clusters and remove cutting edges (by weight, etc).

I find it hard to "accept" that approach (1) which seem to be very naive - outperforms all other.

Also, went over several papers and implemented some of the suggested ideas - none outperformed that naive approach.

I will appreciate if anyone with similar experience has anything to suggest.

Comment: Can you give some details about the model? In particular, I don't know what the purpose of the edge weights is.

Comment: @Juho, the weights are considered as "conduction". vertex $y$ will become sick if the sum of the *weights* of the edges that connect it to *infected* vertices (direct neighbours) is greater than the threshold.